# How to get collection of visible rows at System.Windows.Controls.Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have treeview wrapper of `System.Windows.Controls.Grid`. I can get this object:

```
var winControl = tvObject.Content as System.Windows.Controls.Grid;

if(winControl != null)
{                     
    Console.WriteLine(winControl);
    // Here I want to get only visible rows.
}
```

So, when i touch `Page Down` button- i get new visible rows.
How to get this at `System.Windows.Controls.Grid` programmatically?
Thank you!

Comment: So, are you wanting to output the Grid elements that are showing at any given time?

Comment: @AaronThomas. Yes, i want to get collection of visible by user elements.I want to send command "Page Down", the tree goes throw, and i want to get this visible elements.